# Yii ClientSide Validation on Render Partial not Working

Tags: ajax, yii, renderpartial

I have a Yii form which calls a render partial from another model (team has_many team_members). I want to call via ajax a partial view to add members in team/_form. All works (call, show, save) except for ajax validations (server and client side). If i submit form, member's model  isn't validating, even in client side, it's not validating the required fields.

Any clue?

//_form

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'team-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            'validateOnChange'=>true

        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>
```

//Controller

```
public function actionMember($index)
{
    $model = new TeamMember();
        $this->renderPartial('_member',array(
            'model'=> $model, 'index'=> $index
        )
                ,false,true
                ); 
}  

public function actionCreate()
{
        $model=new Team;
        $members = array();
        if(isset($_POST['Team']))
        {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Team'];

                if(!empty($_POST['TeamMember'])){
                foreach($_POST['TeamMember'] as $team_member)
                            {
                                $mem = new TeamMember();
                                $mem->setAttribute($team_member);
                                if($mem->validate(array('name'))) $members[]=$mem;
                            }
                }
                        $this->redirect(array('team/create','id'=>$model->id,'#'=>'submit-message'));

        }

        $members[]=new TeamMember;
        $this->performAjaxMemberValidation($members);
        $this->render('create',array(
                'model'=>$model,'members'=>$members
        ));

}
```

//_member

```
<div class="row-member<?php echo $index; ?>">
    <h3>Member <?php echo $index+1; ?></h3>
    <div class="row">
    <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model, "[$index]name",array('class'=>'member')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model, "[$index]name",array('class'=>'member')); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::error($model, "[$index]name");?>    
    </div>
</div>
```

`ProcessOutput` was set to true. No dice.
Switch `renderPartial()` to `render()`. No dice.

Comment: MEM, coppettim : are you the same guy ? If not, why did you edit this question and add the last line, how could you know this ??

Comment: @soju: We are not the same guy. But we both are working on this same issue. - And neither of us was able to find the answer yet.

Comment: What are your rules() ?

Comment: @Jorge the rules are on `TeamMember` Model above. That is part of the method rules().

Answer (score 6):

If you will look at the [CActiveForm::run](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1b165448af1716c228acb5b89474890acf0a3ead/framework/web/widgets/CActiveForm.php#L369):

```
$cs->registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform');
//...
$cs->registerScript(__CLASS__.'#'.$id,"jQuery('#$id').yiiactiveform($options);");
```

Then you will understand that you validation will not work, because you render partial and not the whole page. And these scripts show up at the bottom of the page. So you should solve this by execute these scripts.

After you partial is rendered, try to get activeform script which should be stored at the `scipts` array:

```
$this->renderPartial('_member',array('model'=> $model, 'index'=> $index));
$script = Yii::app()->clientScript->scripts[CClientScript::POS_READY]['CActiveForm#team-form'];
```

after, send it with rendered html to page:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$script</script>"
```

Also remember before you will append recieved html on the page you should include `jquery.yiiactiveform.js`, if you not already did it(by render another form, or `registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform')`), on the page from calling ajax request. Otherwise javascript error will raised.

Hope this will help.

**Edit:**
Sorry I'm not understood that you are render part of form and not the whole. But you validation will not work exactly with the same issue. Because `jQuery('#$id').yiiactiveform($options);` script was not created for the field.

Comment: Sorry, didnt understood where to put "$script = Yii::app()->clientScript->scripts[CClientScript::POS_READY]['CActiveForm#team-form'];".. I call my renderPartial in controller, so $script will not be visible in _member view.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is that the ActiveForm saves its attributes to be validated in the "settings" data attribute. I see you are already using indexes so what you need to add the new elements to this settings object in order for the validation to work. After the ajax response this is what must be done:

```
//Get the settings object from the form
var settings = $("#form").data('settings');
//Get all the newly inserted elements via jquery
$("[name^='YourModel']", data).each(function(k, v) {
    //base attribute skeleton
    var base = {
        model : 'YourModel',
        enableAjaxValidation : true,
        errorCssClass : 'error',
        status : 1,
        hideErrorMessage : false,
    };

    var newRow = $.extend({
        id : $(v).attr('id'),
        inputID : $(v).attr('id'),
        errorID : $(v).attr('id') + '_em_',
        name : $(v).attr('name'),
     }, base);
     //push it to the settings.attribute object
     settings.attributes.push(newRow);
 });
 //update the form
 $("#form").data('settings', settings);
```

```

This way the ActiveForm will be aware of the new fields and will validate them.

Comment: Nice work! This helps to solve the problem. Try the whole day to solve this issue. With your solution the fix was made in minutes. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

Well, setting `processOutput` to true in `renderPartial` (in order to make client validation works on newly added fields) will not help in this case since it will only work for `CActiveForm` form and you don't have any form in your `_member` view (only input fields).

A **simple** way to deal with this kind of problem could be to use **only ajax validation**, and use [`CActiveForm::validateTabular()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#validateTabular-detail) in your controller to validate your team members.

Comment: I did it, and _member loads with fields validated. But them not change their status when i enter data inside inputs, keep saying "this field is mandatory" and so on..

Comment: Did you set `enableAjaxValidation` to true and `enableClientValidation` to false ?

Comment: Do you use `validateTabular` ? Add corresponding code to your question

Comment: public function actionMember($index){
            $model = new TeamMember();
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                CActiveForm::validateTabular( array( $model));
                $this->renderPartial('_member',array(
                    'model'=> $model, 'index'=> $index
                )
                        ,false,true
                        ); 
            } 
        }

Comment: Please do not add code like this in your comment, update your question instead... You should use validateTabular in your main action (the one that handles your team form), not in member action...